# Algorithm to draw centered text on a 2D surface

Tags: algorithm, graphics, text, 2d, surface

I am looking for stable algorithm to draw possibly long text horizontally and vertically centered on a 2D surface. This is not language specific, so if you can provide examples in any language it would be very helpful.

The following information I have about the text I want to draw and the surface:

**Text infomation:**

- size of the text in px (line height), is of course way smaller than the height of the surface
- the type face (could be any though)
- simple character set from ASCII32 to ASCII126
- text could be relatively long, words are separated by spaces
- text should break "automatically" on spaces once it will not fit in the width of the surface anymore
- text is in English.

**Surface information:**

- width and height
- x and y coordinates in the global coordinate system (assuming the origin is left top corner of the screen)

I did implement my own approach, but it was very unstable: text spread over the surface, alignment not correct, sometimes not centered at all. Also googled for some good approaches though couldn't find something useful. I hope the stackoverflow community can help me. Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you post your approach? It would be useful to to see what discard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is simple in concept, a bit involved in execution. It involves only a few steps:

```
Split the text into lines that will fit horizontally
Compute the vertical position of the first line
for each line
    Compute its width and the X position
    Display it at the Y position
    Add the line height to the current Y position
```

The hard part is the first step. The rest is easy.

If you have a fixed-width font, then splitting the text into lines isn't too hard. You simply compute how many characters will fit in the given width, index into the string to that position, and then back up to the previous word break. Grab the substring from the start of the previous line (or start of the string for the first line) to that position, and that's your line. Repeat until you get to the end of the string.

With a variable-width font, things are a bit harder because you can't just index into the string by `n * character_width` characters. Instead, you have to guess, test, refine the guess, etc. Every graphics subsystem I've worked with had some kind of `MeasureString` method that would tell me how many pixels it would take to render a string, given a particular font. Given that, what I've done in the past is:

```
Divide the surface width by the font's average character width
Index that far into the string, and find the next (or previous) word break.
Measure the string
If the result is wider than the width, go back one word and measure again.
If the result is narrower than the width, go forward one word and measure again.
Repeat the measure/adjust until you find the string that will fit.
```

Once you've found the substring that will fit, move your start index forward to the start of the next line, and do it again until you reach the end of the string.

Vertically centering the group of lines:

```
starting_position.Y = (Surface_height - (num_lines * line_height)) / 2
```

Horizontally centering a line is easily accomplished:

```
starting_position.X = (Surface_width - Measured_string_width) / 2
```

You have to compute the `starting_position.X` for each line. The Y coordinate is increased by `line_height` for each successive line.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a couple rules to follow

- center every line of text
- if a line's length > page width, start a new line
- vertically center the entire text

So you tokenize your input on spaces.  You will need a collection of strings and a currentIndex.  While lines[currentIndex] + token.length < pageWidth, you can add token to lines[currentIndex].  Once the condition fails, you increment currentIndex and continue.

Once the input is finished, you horizontally center each line.  You have to compute the width of each line in pixels.  Then you do x = pageWidth/2 - lineWidth/2.

Then do the same calculation for your text block height but accounting for all lines (maybe use the bounding rectangle around the text).  Then you can obtain the y value with the same formula y = pageHeight/2 - textHeight /2

Answer (score 0):

This is a personal approach. This will work if the text is 30 characters in length or less and the first word before space is not longer then 15 characters. However this characteristics can be changed very easy. The text will be saved in a 2 dimension array and it will be saved on 2 lines if one line is not big enough. After saving the text centered in the 2 dimensional array it is simple to draw it. I hope this will be helpful.

```
char[][] t = new char[2][15];

public void putTextInMatrix(String text) {
    int len = text.length();
    int start;
    if(len<=15) {
        start = (15-len)/2;
        for (int i=0, j=0; i<15; i++)
            if(i<start || i>=len+start)
                t[0][i] = ' ';
            else {
                t[0][i] = text.charAt(j);
                j++;
            }
    }
    else {
        int last = len;
        for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
            if (text.charAt(i) == ' ')
                last = i;
        }
        start = (15-last)/2;
        for (int i=0, j=0; i<15; i++)
            if(i<start || i>=last+start)
                t[0][i] = ' ';
            else {
                t[0][i] = text.charAt(j);
                j++;
            }

        start = (15-(len-last))/2;
        for (int i=0, j=last+1; i<15; i++)
            if(i<start || j>=len)
                t[1][i] = ' ';
            else {
                t[1][i] = text.charAt(j);
                j++;
            }
    }
}
```